# How to update database from selecting an item in listbox - windows phoene 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing a windows phone 7 application which requires an update operation..I have the following table class.

```
[Table]
public class StudentTable
{

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int StudentID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column (CanBeNull = false)]
    public string StudentName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string StudentClass
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public DateTime regDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Im getting values for each student with the following method..

```
 using (StudentDataContext context = new StudentDataContext(strConnectionString))
        {

            StudentTable newStudent = new StudentTable
            {

                StudentName = textBox1.Text.ToString(),
                StudentClass = textBox2.Text.ToString(), 
                regDate = ((DateTime) datePicker.Value).Date.Add(((DateTime)timePicker.Value).TimeOfDay) 

            };

            context.StudentInfo.InsertOnSubmit(newStudent);
            context.SubmitChanges();

        }
```

and displaying the students in listbox....

```
                 <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="StudentlistBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Loaded="StudentlistBox1_Loaded">
                 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <StackPanel>
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentName}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"></TextBlock>
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentClass}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"></TextBlock>
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding regDate}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Im trying to code so that each selected item in the listbox would lead to a page where i can update the selected record.
If i get the primary key of the selected item, i believe i can do it...How do I select the student in the listbox and pass that students id? any ideas.....im new to windows phone 7..please help..

Answer (score 0):

*Method 1 :- Pass details via navigation*

```
String uri = "/Page2.xaml?param1="+value;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
```

And access in Page 2 on navigated to method :-

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
```

like this:- `QueryString this.NavigationContext.QueryString["param"];`

*Method 2:- Store the id in IsolatedStorage settings*

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
appSettings["paramFromPage1"]=paramValue;
```

And retrieve it using appSettings["paramFromPage1"] by properly parsing it in Page 2

**Method 3:- [May be in Application LifeTimeObjects !!]*